# Added custom PHP IF to WooCommerce template for logged in users, causing visual error for non-logged in

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I added a custom function that shows special features for wholesale customers that are logged in. When a retail customer views the site they do not see this, but, the issue is that it pushes the Description and Reviews section and below, to the right of the page. it is supposed to sit evenly across the content area.

The issue goes away when I am logged into a wholesale customer account or above.

Here is the code I used:

```
<?php
/**
 * Single Product Price, including microdata for SEO
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     1.6.4
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

global $product;
?>
<div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">

    <p class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></p>

    <meta itemprop="price" content="<?php echo $product->get_price(); ?>" />
    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="<?php echo get_woocommerce_currency(); ?>" />
    <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/<?php echo $product->is_in_stock() ?                        'InStock' : 'OutOfStock'; ?>" /> 
</div>
     <div class="custom-pricing">
    <?php if( current_user_can('s2member_level2') || current_user_can('administrator') ) {  ?> 
    <?php echo "MSRP: "; echo the_field('msrp'); ?><br />
    <?php echo "MAP: "; echo the_field('map'); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <p class="clear"></p>
```

--- EDIT

'

```
<p class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></p>

<meta itemprop="price" content="<?php echo $product->get_price(); ?>" />
<meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="<?php echo get_woocommerce_currency(); ?>" />
<link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/<?php echo $product->is_in_stock() ? 'InStock' : 'OutOfStock'; ?>" />
<?php if( current_user_can('s2member_level2') || current_user_can('administrator') ) {  ?> 
<div class="custom-pricing">
<?php echo "MSRP: "; echo the_field('msrp'); ?><br />
<?php echo "MAP: "; echo the_field('map'); ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

'

Comment: Does div.custom-pricing need to be present?  It looks like you only populate the div for certain users, but the div itself will be present for all, changing the flow of your page.  Try placing the div inside the php conditional...

Comment: It does for the styling, I just put the div within the conditional and it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: There may not be enough code to answer your question easily... Another thing I notice is you use an opening brace but no close brace for your if condition.  If you change your open brace to a ':', you should be able to maintain the rest of your syntax, assuming you're using a PHP version high enough to support the syntax.

Comment: That did not work either... Here is a link to an example.

http://orbetinternational.com/product/v-cube-2-jigsaw-cube-flat-printed-glossy-finish/

Comment: From what I can tell, placing the div inside of the conditional (so it only gets inserted into the document if the user is logged in, etc) should resolve the issue.  I was testing it but now the link you provided hits a fatal error.

Comment: I'm still seeing the `custom-pricing` div on the page. But if you switched it back to your original make sure when you try to put both the starting and ending div for `custom-pricing` within your if statement and clear any cache (sgcache &/OR opcache).

Comment: To clarify I added the code change recommended as an answer.

Comment: I tried that, I even copied it exactly... Still nothing.

Comment: The provided test link still does not work.  Please get it working so we can see or put together a fiddle.  Seems like the solution is likely to be simple once we get all parts of the puzzle together.  As @dez mentioned, make sure your web server is not caching the page, and also some frameworks have an independent cache, make sure yours is cleared.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
<div class="custom-pricing">
<?php if( current_user_can('s2member_level2') || current_user_can('administrator') ) {  ?> 
<?php echo "MSRP: "; echo the_field('msrp'); ?><br />
<?php echo "MAP: "; echo the_field('map'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

to:

```
<?php if( current_user_can('s2member_level2') || current_user_can('administrator') ) : ?> 
    <div class="custom-pricing">
    MSRP: <?php echo the_field('msrp'); ?><br />
    MAP: <?php echo the_field('map'); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I have tried this exact, still having the same issue.

Comment: are you logged in as the administrator?

Comment: I logged out to see if it would work. It works when I am logged in how it is supposed to, just doesn't work right when I am not logged in... that's my issue.

Comment: Understood - the theory is that, when logged out, the div of class custom-pricing is still getting styled, even though it's empty.  This is a common mistake.  This would lead to the problem you have, proper styling when logged in, improper styling when logged out.  As I mentioned in a previous comment though, we are going to need something to fiddle with this to narrow it down further.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help. What more would you need in order to help me?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to move the following below the `summary entry-summary` div:

- `div`: `woocommerce-tabs`
- `ul`: `social-share`
- `div:`related products`

While they're inside that div they'll always be on the right because of the `summary entry-summary` `left-margin` of 530px

[image]

Comment: That's the issue, it's not suppose to be under there. it's supposed to span underneath that part AND the images.

Comment: Ahh... "and" the images

Comment: Can you update the question to be more clear. I'll take a look again later for a different solution